# "Not general enough" error deserializing YAML

Tags: rust, serde

I am new to Rust, so I'm sure I'm failing to grok something elementary here, but...

I have a yaml config file, which I want to deserialize to a simple struct. In an earlier version I was able to do this ok from a string literal, but now that I've refactored it to read from a file, I get an error `implementation of '_::_serde::Deserialize' is not general enough`. My function looks like:

```
fn read_config(file: &str) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
    match std::fs::read_to_string(file) {
        Ok(yaml) => match serde_yaml::from_str(&yaml) {
            Ok(c) => c,
            Err(_) => Err("Failed to parse yaml config."),
        },
        Err(_) => Err("Could not open supplied config file"),
    }
}
```

`read_to_string` returns a `Result<String>`, but the signature for `serde_yaml::from_str` wants a `&str`, that is, a borrow. When I give it a borrow, as above, I get the "not general enough" error. When I google that error, I see a lot of discussion about how the deserializer can't use borrowed data; I have to own it first. Isn't that what the original `String` is? If `from_str` can't use a borrow, why does it take a `&str` as an argument? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the string parameter you pass.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_yaml/fn.from_str.html), `from_str` returns a `Result<T>`. In this case, you'd need to call the function with the expected type for `T`. Here, it would be `serde_yaml::from_str::<Config>(&yaml)`.

You'd also need to fix your return statement for `c`. It would be `Ok(c)`, not only `c`.

Comment: Yep, I figured it out just as you posted. The `::<Config>` is redundant if the return is fixed, but that's it. Thanks!

Comment: I posted my answer just a second too late, it seems you already found the solution. You're right, the type inference didn't happen because of the return statement, it is indeed redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, I was missing something fundamental. The problem had nothing to do with borrows or ownership. I missed wrapping the final result in `Ok()`, which screwed up the type inference for my call to `from_str`. Revised function:

```
fn read_config(file: &str) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {    
    match std::fs::read_to_string(file) {        
        Ok(yaml) => match serde_yaml::from_str(&yaml) {
            Ok(c) => Ok(c),
            Err(_) => Err("Failed to parse yaml config."),
        },
        Err(_) => Err("Could not open supplied config file"),
    }
}
```